# define variable in file_get_contents

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php
$a1 = 'http://www.hamooz.com';
$a2 = 'http://www.myegy.com';
$a3 = 'http://www.tech-wd.com/wd';
$num = rand(1,3);

$numb =  '$a'.$num;

echo file_get_contents($numb);
?>
```

the problem appear like:

> Warning: file_get_contents($a3) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ttt\bessah.php on line 9

Answer (score 4):

You need to do `$numb = ${'a'.$num};`, but use the array solution as @Pekka's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Variable variables are a bad practice. Use an array instead.

```
<?php

$a = array();
$a[] = 'http://www.hamooz.com';
$a[] = 'http://www.myegy.com';
$a[] = 'http://www.tech-wd.com/wd';
$num = rand(0,2);

$numb = $a[$num];

echo file_get_contents($numb);
?>
```

For this specific task however, there is also a [shortcut](http://php.net/array_rand):

> array_rand (  )
>
> Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries.

Comment: @AD7six true. This was more for teaching purposes but array_rand  definitely needs to be mentioned, I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  @Pekka you're going to complicate your code, 
but if you absolutly want to use dynamic variables you can do :

```
<?php
$a1="hello";
$b=1;
echo ${"a$b"};
?>
```

Comment: This is a nice obfuscation method.